# How to find the definition of desc in ocaml source code?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

In OCaml source code 4.07, in `typing/typemod.ml`, line 1452:

```
let type_str_item env srem {pstr_loc = loc; pstr_desc = desc} =
```

I can't find where `desc` is defined. The function `type_str_item` is defined in the `type_structure` function, but `desc` is not one of `type_structure`'s parameters.

I can't find the definition of it anywhere, and I am going to pattern match against it, so I cannot ignore it.

How to navigate OCaml source code to find definitions?

Comment: "How to navigate OCaml source code to find definitions?" For that, [Merlin](https://ocaml.github.io/merlin/) is the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: I already use vscode+merlin,but press f12 after right click the value,it tell me can't find.In other ocaml source file can tell me where the value is defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code fragment is not using a variable, it is binding one through pattern matching. This is a record pattern which binds the variable `desc` to the `pstr_desc` field.

For navigating ocaml sources there is the `merlin` code assistance tool which provides a jump-to-definition facility for some common editors (as well as various other features). However, that would not help much here as you are already looking at the definition of `desc`.

Comment: Thanks.My ide is vscode+merlin,on ubuntu 16.but if I right click on the pstr_loc,or loc,or str_desc,or desc,then press f12 to find the definition,merlin tell me it can't find anything.My vscode+merlin's config is correct,I can see the type of a value or function